# how to capture logger values using clearml

Tags: python, pytorch, clearml

I am using clearml for testing algorithms and it works well with library [Stable Baselines 3](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/tree/f8a08690737000e4d23eb643a21d70486ece038b), in which clearml automatically captures all the output and plot them in the Scalars tab.

However, when I switched to another library [PFRL](https://github.com/pfnet/pfrl) clearml no longer output anything to the Scalar tab. After looking into the code I found PFRL outputs statistics using `logger.info`, which seemed to be the reason of empty Scalars tab (but there was output in the Console tab).
I am wondering is there any method that I can make clearml automatically collect them into the Scalars tab.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the task logger to report these statistics using the `task.logger` property.
See the [scalars reporting example](https://github.com/allegroai/clearml/blob/81de18dbce08229834d9bb0676446a151046e6a7/examples/reporting/scalar_reporting.py) for a code sample on how to do this.